# Automatically changed Profile pic and decreased points

Tags: support

Today I just logged to magento.stackexchange.com and shocked to see that my Profile Pic is changed and Reputation point is decreased (-125), saying `−xx  User was removed`

[image]

Can any one say OR explain, what's happened to my profile ?

Answer (score 4):

All I can tell you is that your -125 points come from the fact that a user that upvoted your questions/answers got deleted. [Read more about this here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed).
I have no idea what happened to your avatar.
I only see in the activity report 2 avatar changes from May 30.
Maybe you changed the avatar on stackoverflow.com and you also clicked to change it on every other site in the stackexchange network.

Comment: but this is much disruptive to me (results in -125). Can't they use that "special deletion", stated in the link you provided ?

Comment: That's how the delete works. Special deletion applies in special cases. I guess this was not a special case.

Comment: This is ridiculous. If user is removed, why it should affect my points ?

Comment: I don't make up the rules. [read this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/224252) and the answers. Maybe you will understand why this is needed and why it happens.